# Add "success" and "error" callbacks to $http.get inside of "then"

Tags: angularjs

I'm aware that when using `$http.get` it is possible to chain callbacks for success or error, like such:

```
$http.get(someUrl).success(...).error(...);
```

However, I've run into the following case in my code dealing with promises:

```
parseUrl(obj.getUrl()).then($http.get)
```

Currently I am just handling the callback by adding a `then` and a `catch` for error, but is it possible to use the more seemingly appropriate `success` and `error` callbacks in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, `then` accept two functions, the first is success, the second is error.

```
var succ = function() {};
var erro = function() {};
parseUrl(obj.getUrl()).then(succ, erro);
```

[the-promise-api on angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)